# Internal Implementation of AsEnumerable() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-construction, covariance, contravariance

I have two questions:

**Question 1 Background :**
I noticed when looking at the implementation of 'AsEnumerable()' method in LINQ from Microsoft, which was:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{ 
   return source;
}
```

**Question 1:** 
I was expecting some kind of casting or something here , but it simply returns the value it was passed. How does this work ?

**Question 2/3 Background :**
I have been trying to understand Covariance , contravariance and Invariant. I think, I have a vague understanding that 'in' and 'out' keywords determine the polymorphic behavior when assigning a subtype to a parent type.

**Question 2:** 
I know from reading that IEnumerable is covariant, and List is invariant then why is this not possible :

```
List<char> content = "testString".AsEnumerable();
```

**Question 3:**
If IList implements IEnumerable then why is this not possible :

```
IEnumerable<char> content1 = "testString";
IList<char> content2 = content1;
```

Please help me understanding, thank you in advance.

Comment: AsEnumerable() forces the query to execute immediately in other LINQ providers like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework. It's probably added to LINQ to Objects for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The input argument is already known to have the type `IEnumerable<TSource>`. Why would it need to cast anything? Casting the objects to the type `TSource` would have no effect, since they're already guaranteed to be of that type (or a more derived type).
2. You can't assign a value of type `IEnumerable<char>` to a variable of type `List<char>`. I think you're thinking in reverse here; `List<char>` derives from `IEnumerable<char>`, not the other way around. This has nothing to do with `List<T>` being invariant. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (to be more precise, the type parameter `T` is covariant), which gives us this situation:

   ```
   IEnumerable enumerable = Enumerable.Empty<string>(); // Allowed
   IEnumerable<string> genericEnumerable = enumerable; // Not allowed
   ```
3. Again, `IList<char>` inherits from `IEnumerable<char>`, not the other way around. You can do this:

   ```
   IList<char> content1 = "testString".ToList();
   IEnumerable<char> content2 = content1;
   ```

   What you're asking for doesn't make sense, I'm afraid, and it's nothing to do with covariance. The fact that `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant means that you're allowed to do this:

   ```
   IEnumerable<object> asObject = new List<string>() { "test" };
   ```

   But `List<T>` is invariant, so you can't do this:

   ```
   List<object> asObject = new List<string>() { "test" };
   ```

Comment: I need some time to digest that !

Comment: In response to 1st answer, I understand, so If I can directly assigned a value of derived object to an instance of parent type then what purpose does 'AsEnumerable()' solve ?

Comment: In response to 2nd answer, Ok so Why is IEnumerable<string> enumerable = (IEnumerable)Enumerable.Empty<string>(); not possible ? IEnumerable<T> implements IEnumerable so why is the compiler complaining ?

Comment: @RaM You're thinking in reverse again. `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`, which means that you can assign an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable`, not the other way around. In the example you quoted, the compiler doesn't know that the variable actually *is* an instance of `IEnumerable<string>`. I've edited the example to hopefully be a little clearer.

Comment: As for AsEnumerable(), I'm not too sure what the point of it is either, to be honest. The remarks section of the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) indicates that it could be used to "hide" special implementations of other LINQ methods like `Where` and `Select`, but that seems like a strange rationale to me. Maybe I've just never needed it.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken `AsEnumerable` is very useful in LINQ to SQL/EF as it splits the server side (translation) and client side processing of the LINQ statement.